# How do I link CSS and JS files to my HTML file for github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I've just moved to github pages, and I have an index.html, an index.js and a style.css all in the same folder(master I believe). I've tried the following way to link the js and the css to the html:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master/style.css">`

`<script src="master/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

However, it just doesn't seem to work. In the middle, the CSS seemed to link once, but then after that when I tried to link the JS too, the whole thing stopped working again. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are in the same folder, I'm not sure you need to type folder's name. Try to remove "master/" in your two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

When you link stuff to your html file, the path is relative to that file.
So if style.css and index.js are in the same folder, you just link them by providing file names only.
If those file were in the folder above, you would link them by "../style.css" and "../index.js"
If those file were in the subfolder (in relation to index.html), you would link them by "subfolder/style.css" and "subfolder/index.js"

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Helped me understand why my fix worked!